# Formatting Excel Chart Element With VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, format, axis

I am trying to format the font of an Excel chart X-Axis with VBA so that the text of the axis matches the font of the background, leaving the text intact but invisible.  I don't want to delete this element of the chart entirely so I can use the space for other things (I am pasting a picture that will occupy the space).

To do this I recorded the below macro, but when I play it back it fails.

```
Sub Macro23()
' Macro23 Macro
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

I know that I can tweak the recorded macro to avoid the "selection" process and access the commands more directly, and I have tried that as well.  But whether I run the macro as recorded, or tweaked, the result is the same ... it fails on the line (untweaked shown):

```
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "matches the font of the background" do you mean the _colour_ of the background? "when I play it back it fails" what does "it fails" mean, exactly? What error message do you get?

Comment: Yes, I am changing the color

Comment: The error that arises is Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'TextFrame2' of object 'ChartFormat' failed

Comment: I figured it out after multiple trial and error attempts... works with this code line:

Comment: ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Color = vbWhite